# Read a csv file in Flink 1.15 using Table API

Tags: apache-flink, flink-table-api

I'm doing a simple tutorial with `flink` + `java` using `Table API`. What I want to do is really simple - I want to read a csv file from a local filesystem, using a schema and print it out.

The way I'm doing this is this(the code below is compiled from samples from Flink's website tutorial section):

```
package p1;

import org.apache.flink.table.api.*;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.utils.ParameterTool;


public class CabAggregation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);
        EnvironmentSettings settings = EnvironmentSettings
                .newInstance()
                .inBatchMode()
                .build();

        TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(settings);
        final Schema schema = Schema.newBuilder()
                .column("cab_id", DataTypes.INT())
                .column("cab_plate", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("cab_make", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("cab_driver", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("active_trip", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("pickup_location", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("target_location", DataTypes.STRING())
                .column("num_pass", DataTypes.INT())
                .build();


        tableEnv.createTemporaryTable("cabs",
                TableDescriptor
                        .forConnector("filesystem")
                        .schema(schema)
                        .option("path", "file:///Users/virtual/Downloads/cabs.csv")
                        .format(FormatDescriptor.forFormat("csv").build())
                        .build());

        Table result = tableEnv.from("cabs").select("*");
        result.execute().print();
    }
}
```

Running this gives me this:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'filesystem' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath.

Available factory identifiers are:

blackhole
datagen
print
```

Now, it seems evident that somehow CSV is not available as a factory identifier. I can't figure out why.
I'm building the project with `maven`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be needing these dependencies. Have you added them?

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-connector-files</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-csv</artifactId>
    <version>${flink.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. One quick question, I'm very new to the whole java+flink thing. At some point it was obvious that I need to add `flink-csv` to the XML, but then `flink-connector-files` was never mentioned directly. I remember reading in the tutorial that I might need `flink-connectors-*`, but that's it. In this ecosystem what is a good way to understand what specific deps you need for this or that functionality, so far the experience of searching for them was a rather frustrating one.

Comment: The documentation page for each connector should specify the dependencies involved, but it's certainly possible that this is, in at least some cases, either missing or hard to find. If you see room for improvement, please create a JIRA ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/FLINK/issues/.